# NestJS Cron scheduler not working with PrismaService

Tags: nestjs

I'm facing a problem with the Cron scheduler. Below is the behavior of the `WelcomeEmailService`.

---

- If I don't add `PrismaService` in the constructor, the Cron starts and works fine and `Process` is printed on the console every 10 seconds.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { PrismaService } from '../core/prisma/prisma.service';

@Injectable()
export class WelcomeEmailService {
  constructor(
    // private prisma: PrismaService
  ) {}

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
  async process() {
    console.log('Process');
  }
}
```

---

- If I add `PrismaService` in the constructor, the Cron doesn't start. I get a warning in the console.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron, CronExpression } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { PrismaService } from '../core/prisma/prisma.service';

@Injectable()
export class WelcomeEmailService {
  constructor(
    private prisma: PrismaService
  ) {}

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
  async process() {
    console.log('Process');
  }
}
```

```
Cannot register cron job "WelcomeEmailService@process" because it is defined in a non static provider.
```

I need help in resolving this issue.